# Exterior of a torus knot is Seifert-fibered.

Tags: knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

I am trying to show that if $K\subset S^3$ is a $(p,q)$ torus knot, then the knot exterior $X_K=S^3\setminus N(K)$ is Seifert-fibered space, where $N(K)$ is a tubular neighborhood of $K$ in $S^3$.

It's obvious to me that the base space of such a fibration should have connected boundary, since $X_K$ has torus boundary. So, I've tried to define such a fibration on a disk (maybe by taking the standard fibered torus $D^2\times S^1$, and replacing a regular fiber from the interior with a singular fiber of some order depending on $(p,q)$). However, I don't know how to argue such a construction. Even if I can manage to make the right fiber replacement, I don't know how to show that the resulting space would be homeomorphic to $X_K$.

Can someone give me a hint about this?

Comment: Instead of trying to find a fibration on a disc, instead find disjoint circles filling out $S^3$ including the circle $K$.

Comment: Thanks @LeeMosher! Here is how I think: Take two solid tori $T_1, T_2$. Apply $2\pi p/q$ twist to a meridional disk in $T_1$ and  $2\pi q/p$ twist to a meridional disk in $T_2$. After the twists, $T_1,T_2$ are still solid tori, but $T_1$ is fibered by $(p,q)$-knots and $T_2$ is fibered by $(q,p)$-knots (away from their cores). Now glue $T_1,T_2$ along their (meridian to pararlel, parallel to meridian). The resulting space is $S^3$ and fibers of the tori match up along the boundary by construction. Hence, we obtain a Seifert-fibration of $S^3$ containing the $(p,q)$-knot $K$ as a regular fiber.

Comment: That sounds correct.

Comment: Finally, removing a (standardly fibered) tubular neighborhood of $K$, we obtain $X_K$ with a Seifert fibration coming from the ambient $S^3$.