# Does a torus knot give a Seifert fibering of the 3-sphere?

Tags: manifolds, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology, orbifolds

Let $K$ be a $(p,q)$ torus knot on the torus $T_1$. Via the map
\begin{equation*}
H=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
$K$ becomes a $(q,p)$ torus knot on $T_2=H(T_1)$. If we fill in both these tori to become solid tori $D_1$ and $D_2$, then
\begin{equation*}
S^3 = D_1\cup_H D_2
\end{equation*}

This seems to give a Seifert fibering of $S^3$, and the comments to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1674924/320311) suggest that's true. But wouldn't the base orbifold be a a 2-sphere with two conical points of order $p$ and $q$, which is a "bad" orbifold? I also know that if we remove a tubular neighborhood of $K$ in $S^3$, then we **do** get a Seifert fibering of the knot complement.

I'd like to figure out where my understanding is breaking down. Is this an actual Seifert fibering of $S^3$ or not?

Comment: "But wouldn't the base orbifold be a a 2-sphere with two conical points of order $p$ and $q$" - not at all, it would be $S^2(p,p)$. How did you come up with a cone point of order $q$?

Comment: @MoisheKohan: sorry, wouldn't the central fibers of $D_1$ and $D_2$ give us the conical points? I'm basing this on my understanding of the case where $K$ is the trefoil knot (a $(2,3)$ torus knot), where $S^3\setminus K$ has base orbifold a disk, with two conical points, one of order $2$ and one of order $3$?

Comment: You are right, for some reason I was thinking about lens spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base space of a Seifert fibered 3-manifold can indeed be a bad 2-orbifold, so your intuition is not breaking down. See [this math overflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36312/getting-rid-of-exceptional-fibers-by-passing-to-finite-covers/36323#36323) for reference including a discussion which incorporates bad base orbifolds. So yes, your description of the base orbifold associated to a $(p,q)$ torus knot is correct.

Comment: Thanks for answering! So is my description of the Seifert fibering coming from the knot $K$ correct? (Just to be sure.)

Comment: That's correct.